# How can I send text messages to an e-mail address?

Tags: email, google-voice, text-messaging

I'd like to use Google Voice to send messages from my to my mother's e-mail address, since she doesn't have a cell phone.

Google Voice won't allow me to send a message to an e-mail address.

How do I send a message to an e-mail address using Google Voice?

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to just send emails?

Comment: For the same reason Twitter is more popular than Wordpress, and iMessage/googlechat is more popular than e-mail, and why young people text more than they e-mail. The constraint of a character limit decreases perceived effort. With e-mails, (1) I feel like it will be more work and I avoid doing it, and (2) the other person expects a more effort and more length. Text messaging is a more natural format for casually chatting back and forth. Empirically, I've observed that I text my dad almost daily, and rarely send e-mails to my mom simply because it's more mental effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an SMS to a phone number, and have it end up as an email message, you will need a third party service that will accept the message and then resend it as an email on your behalf.  Searching Google for "SMS email relay" brings up some interesting results.

I'm not aware that Google Voice or iMessage in and of themselves provide such a relay service.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a Google Voice account in your mom's name, which will give you a phone number for your mom. Then you can set it up to [forward texts to her email](http://support.google.com/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=160203), and she'll be able to respond.

Remember, of course, she will still be interacting with emails, so there will be a mismatch in the amount of perceived effort.

Answer (score 0):

[This IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/9114) will let you send an SMS to IFTTT tagged `#emailmom` and will then email the text message to the email address you have specified.

This doesn't help going in the reverse direction, but there are other IFTTT recipes for that.